# how to get the count of column data based on some condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the excel with two columns like below

```
ID       Address

GID1    address1

GID2    address2

GID1    address1

GID8    address1

GID2    address8
```

so i want to get , for all same ID's , count of address as below and wanted to know the excel formula for this

```
ID       Address   Count of Same Address per GID

GID1    address1      2

GID2    address2      1

GID1    address1      2

GID8    address1      1

GID2    address8      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `COUNTIFS` because you have two conditions for your counts -- ID and address.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,$A2,$B$2:$B$6,$B2)
```

Place this formula in `C2` and fill down.

More information on `COUNTIFS`: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx